# Is it possible to return a nested list as IO()

Tags: haskell

I have some simple functions and I need makeMove to return IO():

```
toPole :: Show a => [a] -> [a] -> String
toPole fpole spole = show(head fpole:spole)

fromPole :: Show a => [a] -> String
fromPole fpole = show (tail fpole)

makeMove :: [a] -> [a] -> IO ()
makeMove [] _ = return ()
makeMove fpole spole = putStr (unwords p)
     where p = [fromPole fpole, toPole fpole spole]
```

The idea is that I have two lists, and I want to move the first item of the list `fpole` to the second list `spole`, and print them as a nested list `[[],[]]` with `putStr`. Is there a way to achieve this? I've tried different things with the return type of `toPole` and `fromPole`, but figured it was easier to convert makeMove to IO() if the return type was `String`.

The error I get arises from `fromPole fpole` in `where p = [fromPole fpole, ...`:

```
No instance for (Show a) arising from a use of ‘fromPole’
```

Comment: Are you typing the explicit type signatures in the terminal? `ghci` can infer the `Show a` constraint from the use of `show`, but won't  override an explicit type signature that lacks the constraint.

Comment: The full error is quite informative. You should definitely read it carefully. It even tells you how to fix the problem right in the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`makeMove` also needs the `Show a` constraint. As it stands, you are saying that `makeMove` can accept lists of *any* type as arguments, but then you try to pass those possibly `Show`-less values to `fromPole`.

```
makeMove :: Show a => [a] -> [a] -> IO ()
makeMove [] _ = return ()
makeMove fpole spole = putStr (unwords p)
     where p = [fromPole fpole, toPole fpole spole]
```

---

A cleaner implementation wouldn't have either `toPole` or `fromPole` making any assumptions about the list elements; in fact, they are barely necessary. You can define `makeMove` (arguably more clearly) without them.

```
transfer :: [a] -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
transfer (x:xs) ys = (xs, (x:ys))

makeMove :: Show a => [a] -> [a] -> String
makeMove fpole spole = let (fpole', spole') = transfer fpole spole
                       in unwords [fpole', spole']

showMove :: Show a => [a] -> [a] -> IO ()
showMove fpole spole = print (makeMove fpole spole)
```

Here, I've decomposed the function into three logical parts:

1. `transfer` simply moves an element from one pole to the other.
2. `makeMove` creates a `String` from the result of `transfer`
3. `showMove` outputs the result of the move.

As much work as possible is kept in pure functions, with only `showMove` having any dependency on `IO`.